# A phonegap-like for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, cross-platform, cordova

I have a mobile web app (HTML & CSS). I use Phonegap to embed it for Android, iOS, BB, etc, but it doesn't work for windows mobile for the moment.

Is there a way doing that in windows phone, or do I have to wait for a new version of Phonegap ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap is not available for Windows Phone 7 at the moment, however, it will most likely appear soon. Much of the functionality that PhoneGap requires from the native APIs will only be available in the upcoming WP7 Mango release.

See Matt Lacey's partial implementation of PhoneGap for WP7 here:

http://blog.mrlacey.co.uk/2010/08/wp7dev-phonegap-and-windows-phone-7.html

There is an alternative project here:

http://htmlappwp7.codeplex.com/

However, I would recommend the more 'standard' PhoneGap approach.

**UPDATE:**

PheneGap is [now in beta for WP7](http://blogs.nitobi.com/jesse/2011/09/08/pg-wp7mango/), I have written a blog post which shows [an example PhoneGap app for WP7](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/09/developing-windows-phone-7-html5-apps-with-phonegap/).

Comment: Ok, wp7 support should appear in next phonegap release, I can wait :D

Answer (score 0):

The current WP7 development code is available on github here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-wp7